# How can you change the placeholder in the search field of a WP theme?

Tags: wordpress, widget, themes, placeholder

As is often the case, there is some questionable English in a theme I purchased and it appears to be hardcoded. It actually has a different placeholder for mobile vs. desktop (I'm okay with the desktop one, which is "Search here...").

It seems to be a theme-specific widget, but I was unable to find a php file or template to change that language in. Any ideas?

Comment: <div class="form-content search-box results-search">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="searchfield txt-livesearch input" name="s" value="" placeholder="Im searchings for...">
                    </div>
                </div>

Comment: Not sure why, but my code excerpt didn't make it to the page, added it in comments. (Sorry, first post!)

Comment: it's easy to create a custom search form, only create a form and set input name to 's'

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the string was in wp-content/themes/ThemeName/framework/theme-functions.php